# email enconding improper result, send from php mailer in zencart 1.3.8

Tags: php, email, encoding, character-encoding, zen-cart

I don't really know much about encoding other then knowing I'm having a problem with it, I'm using the recover cart sales module in zercant 1.3.8 to send an automatic email to people who abandoned their carts without completing the purchase, the problem is that my language uses words like "cão, macarrão, há, número, contúdo", and it's writing them all wrong,

example from an email sent:

mas que nÃ£o completou a transacÃ§Ã£o.

How do I solve this?

the email header sent is this:

```
To: [edited for stackoverflow]
Subject: [edited for stackoverflow]
X-PHP-Script: [edited for stackoverflow]
Date: Sun, 20 May 2012 04:44:36 -0500
Return-Path: [edited for stackoverflow]
From: [edited for stackoverflow]
Reply-to: [edited for stackoverflow]
Message-ID: [edited for stackoverflow]
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73] via Zen Cart
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

Can you please help me get the email correct?

Answer (score 0):

The email headers are fine (ã is part of ISO-8859-1) - so it's on the ZenCart side.
I don't know much about ZenCart but maybe your website is in UTF-8?

PHPMailer default encoding is iso-8859-1, you can try to change it:

```
<?php
$phpMailerObj->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

You should also try different email clients. And for your own good, use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: the problem is that when I use UTF-8 all accents in letters work except one, � and then I get that symbol on it, please help

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems:

- You're using an obsolete version of Zen Cart with known security problems. If your site has been hacked then it's possible that any normal advice given may not work because of alterations made to your site by malicious intruders. You really ought to upgrade to a contemporary version. Your version was released in 2007.
- As Damien suggested, you've most likely got mixed character sets. Your database and language files and database connection all need to use the same character set configuration. Support for specifying character sets was added in v1.3.9h and improved further in v1.5.0.
  You're using v1.3.8 which requires specific code alterations in order to add support for alternate character sets, which again substantiates your need to upgrade.